# Presenting a fullscreen style view controller on top of a custom presentation style view controller, how to trigger viewDidDisappear?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a custom presentation style view controller `B`, modal presentation style set to `UIModalPresentationCustom`. I have presented `B` on vc `A` modally.

Now, on `B` I present a new vc `C` (modally) with `UIModalPresentationFullscreen`, `B` being the source now. How can I make sure that `viewDidAppear/Disappear` does get called on `B` and subsequently on `A`.

I am not using Storyboards. All of this is done programmatically.

Comment: Okay, some clarification is needed. Using `present` and modally doing it full-screen, are you trying to go **A >> B >> C** straight back all the way to **A**, or "unwind" (without using segues going back to "A" but through "B"?

Comment: @dfd I'm going back to B so yes unwinding in a sense but I am not using segues

Comment: If you wish to simply go back to B from C, try using `viewWillAppear`. All you are really doing is pushing C onto a stack on top of B and then in `dismiss` for C, `viewWillAppear` will be triggered in B. Now, if you need to do something fancier, like go all the way back to A from C, I set up a simple project that requires B being a delegate of C. B will appear briefly, but it will know to "unwind" all the way back to A. Pretty much, when using `present` and wanting to pass data from back, I think the delegate pattern is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If your view controllers are set up in storyboard, you could do the following:

You could use an **unwind segue**:
In the viewController to that you want to return **to**, insert

```
@IBAction func unwindToTargetVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

In StoryBoard, go to the viewController **from** that you want to return and control-drag the viewController icon to the exit icon in the top bar.
You will be presented with IBAction options. Select here the unwind segue action that you have defined in your target viewController.
In the document outline of your viewController select the unwind segue and open to the attributes inspector. Enter here as identifier the name of your unwind segue.
Eventually you can trigger the segue, i.e. the return to your target viewController, by the following code:

```
@IBAction func returnToTargetViewControler(_ sender: Any) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToTargetVC", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: The question clearly talks about `present`, not segues. It actually says vcB is "presented on top of vcA modally". How does this answer the question?

Comment: Don't you setup your view controllers in Storyboard?

Comment: I don't always do that. I usually do when I want to embed my VCs in a navigation controller. But that's a personal preference. Nowhere in the OP were Storyboards mentioned. But *"presenting... on top of..."* was. I asked for clarification. EDIT: I don't disagree that a segue might be the better route to go - but is that isn't being used (from A to B to C) than an unwind segue definitely isn't the answer.

Comment: Well, in the question, it was neither mentioned that the VCs were presented programmatically. So I think, if they are setup in Storyboard, my answer is valid; if not, then not. Thanks for the hint. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, sorry for the confusion but I am not setting these up in Storyboard, I am programmatically creating them and presenting them.